# PHP JSON encoded output non compatible with Javascript Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

[Here](http://web.smartplc.it/SmartTRK/lib/jsondata.php?LAT1=41.07892507753545&LAT2=41.16246381676556&LNG1=14.723925433349564&LNG2=14.860224566650345) I've built a script to generate the following **JSON** output:

```
[{"lat":41.081348,"lon":14.73292,"type":"F"},...,{"lat":41.09837,"lon":14.83176,"type":"F"}]
```

However when I try to get data using the following Javascript code:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: 'myJSONscript.php',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                console.log("data:"+data);
                console.log("status:"+status);
                console.log("xhr:"+xhr);
                }, //End Success
            error: function () {
                alert("ERROR");
                }
            });
```

I get just an empty data variable 
(in other words the console returns 
data:*empty*,
 
status:success,
 
xhr:[object Object]).
The JSON output is valid (tested with [JSONlint](http://jsonlint.com/)) and was built using the following code:

```
$arr=array();
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
$element=array('lat'=>floatval($row['LATITUDE']),'lon'=>floatval($row['LONGITUDE']),'type'=>$row['TYPE']);
    array_push($arr, $element);
    }
$data=json_encode($arr,true);
header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
echo $data;
```

I cannot figure out what's wrong...

Comment: Have you inspected the request in the Network tab in browser console?

Comment: read the fabulous manual for [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) ... your syntax is incorrect. Remove the `true` parameter.

Comment: if you run the url `myJSONscript.php` directly in a browser, do you get the correct json printed?

Comment: @dewd: Yes the JSON output is correct and validated with http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @YvesLeBorg the JSON output was validated by http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: put a `'` at the end of `myJSONscript.php`

Comment: @YvesLeBorg, done but was just a mistyping error in the post, the real code is ok. Removing the 'true' parameter doesn't change anything.

Comment: are you sure you're actually calling the script? as @Gothdo suggested, check the network activity in the console.

Comment: @Gothdo I can see the call in the Google Chrome Concole window. So the call is performed correctly. The problem is in the JSON format. If I change it with another source of JSON data as for example openweather or google-finance it is ok but I see in this case that the JSON format is different and looks like: 
{"items":[{"lat":41.081348,"lon":14.73292,"type":"F"},...,{"lat":41.09837,"lon":14.83176,"type":"F"}]}
So the question is why I need this useless "items" key and why PHP json_encode doesn't do that for me? and above all, why http://jsonlint.com/ says that everything is ok?

Comment: ok.  Try to use error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert(status);
        } to get some kind of hint. Also check logs php side to see if the server is giving you any indication.

Comment: ok @YvesLeBorg, I prepared a copy of the JSON data generator for your tests:
http://web.smartplc.it/SmartTRK/lib/jsondata.php?LAT1=41.07892507753545&LAT2=41.16246381676556&LNG1=14.723925433349564&LNG2=14.860224566650345 
As you will see the JSON data are absolutely ok and validated by http://jsonlint.com/ so it's weird...

Comment: the console on data says just [ ]
so it's empty, but the Ajax function is in success state!

Comment: Fixed!
the contentType: "application/json" cannot be used together with dataType: "json", removing contentType solves the problem.

Comment: @PowerEngineering : make this an answer and accept it. The question and the answer are useful to others !

Answer (score 2):

Fixed! the `contentType: "application/json"` cannot be used together with `dataType: "json"`, removing **contentType** solved the problem.